# Should we remove the "in Esperanto" in the title of the questions?

Tags: discussion

Often, there is a superfluos "in Esperanto" in the name of the question. For exemple : *How to translate X in Esperanto?* *How to do Y in Esperanto?*

Should we remove them, tolerate them, or encourage them?

Answer (score 8):

It might help improve visibility in Google searches; other than that I don't think it matters a whole lot one way or the other.

Comment: I’m in favour of leaving it in if someone writes it because even though it’s redundant making any edit to a person’s question comes at the cost of potentially annoying them and this change really doesn’t matter enough to risk it. It’s also nice to have when the question appears out of context such as in the list of ‘hot network questions’.

Comment: This is definitely more useful for Google searches. I agree that we should not edit questions though, although I strongly believe we should include "in Esperanto" to raise the question's visibility in Google and increase our amount of daily visitors.

Answer (score 5):

It is kind of redundant. Not sure if it requires active removal, though; depends on the overall context.

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to add *Esperanto* in the question titles: The site is only about Esperanto, so questions about translating a word in other languages are off-topic. There isn't any ambiguity in a title like *How do I translate **solar system**?* because it can just ask how to translate in Esperanto.

As for helping searching questions about Esperanto, the meta data added to the site should be sufficient for the search engines. The following tags are only a part of the meta tags added to a question page.

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon image_src" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/sites/esperanto/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=3001edd22410">
<link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="Esperanto Language Stack Exchange" href="/opensearch.xml">
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
<meta name="twitter:domain" content="esperanto.stackexchange.com"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />

<meta property="og:image" itemprop="image primaryImageOfPage" content="http://cdn.sstatic.net/sites/esperanto/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=3001edd22410&a" />
<meta name="twitter:title" property="og:title" itemprop="title name" content="Kio estas la diferenco inter &quot;kreaĵo&quot; kaj &quot;verko&quot;?" />
```

The post is clearly stated to be part of a site about Esperanto.